# How do I change the current layout of my directories, and still have my C++ program be buildable?

Tags: eclipse, file, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to change how my files are structured for a decently sized C++ project in Eclipse. I want to put all my source files into one folder called `src`, so I make the source folder and just put everything else into it. This does not work, and I do not know why.

I have looked into the source locations property, and src is definitely there along with every other folder.

I am getting the error that some of the files do not exist, so it obviously cannot find the files it needs.

I want every folder that's not `src` to be in `src`:

[image: A picture of this specific case.]

Comment: If you want a single src folder, why do you leave all the other folders as source location? Anyway, without code, screenshot, and exact error message, there is little we can do.

Comment: @JBNizet I want to have subfolders in the src folder. Its pretty hard to learn how to effectively use an IDE. Ill upload a picture if I can.

Comment: A source folder must contain a Java package tree. Not arbitrary subfolders. If you code is in the package com.foo.bar, then a source folder **must** have the com directory matching with the com package as its direct child.

Comment: @JBNizet the reason its so hard to learn how to use one effectively is because everyone explains like I should know every term. What you wrote doesnt mean a lot to me currently. This is for a c++ project.

Comment: I assumed you were talking about a Java project, since Eclipse is mainly used for Java. I don't know much about C++. But your screenshot shows that you **already** have everything about src. Eclipse just chooses to display every source folder under src as a separate entry. Why do you care?

Comment: @JBNizet My friend, I have said in the initial post that I put all the folders into /src, but now it won't compile because some files cannot find other files. I care because I care about my code. I want it to be laid out correctly, nicely and effectively. As the project is growing, the need for structure is too. You aren't contributing one bit to the actual problem at hand.

Comment: I am. For example, without my contribution, you still wouldn't have said that you're talking about a C++ project, although it's obviously critical information. And once you finally said that, I said: "I don't know much about C++.". So, tag your post with the correct tags, and wait for someone who knows about C++ to answer. Don't blame me for your bad question.

Comment: @PatrickChristie Please give an example to reproduce this issue, tell the exact error message and when and where you get the error. Please tell also which kind of C++ project this is (what have to be choosen in _File > New > ..._ to create the same kind of C++ project?).